# Binary crossentropy and multi-label classification with from_logits set to True do not work as desired

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to have a multi-label classification task, and I want to implement the network using `Tensorflow`. I know that I have to use `BCE` as the loss and `Sigmoid` as the activation of the last layer. I wanted to have the stable computation, so I decided to utilise the option `from_logits` set to `True` for `BCE`. The problem was that I tried to use the following code to check everything is ok, but the results do not match. In the following code, `a` corresponds to two samples. In the first one, the last two categories are present. `b` corresponds to the output of a network which is not passed through the `Sigmoid` activation function.

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], 
          [0, 1, 0, 1.]]) 
b = np.array([[18, -20, 20, 20], 
              [-18, 0., -10, 12]])     
b_sigmoid = tf.sigmoid(b)     
lf = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
lt = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

calling `lf(a, b_sigmoid)` yields `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.0147683492886337>`, whilst calling `lt(a, b)` yields `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.336649845037007>`. As you see, they do not match. Can someone tell me why? They have to yield the same or at least a similar number with a small difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the [epsilon constant](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/epsilon) used as a fuzz factor by Keras to avoid numerical instability and NaN values (like the result of `log(-1.)`).

This constant is used in the calculation of the BinaryCrossentropy when `from_logits` is set to `False`. By default, this epsilon value is set to `1e-7`, but this induce some imprecision in the binary cross entropy calculation. That's why the [recommended usage is to use `from_logits=True`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy), where the method to calculate the cross entropy does not rely on such a constant.

If you want the two results to be closer to each other, you can use [`tf.keras.backend.set_epsilon`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_epsilon) to set the fuzz factor to a lower value. Using a value around `1e-15` yields closer results for the two methods. (But could lead to numerical instabilities elsewhere).

```
tf.keras.backend.set_epsilon(1e-15)
a = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1], 
          [0, 1, 0, 1.]]) 
b = np.array([[18, -20, 20, 20], 
              [-18, 0., -10, 12]])     
b_sigmoid = tf.sigmoid(b)     
lf = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()
lt = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
```

Testing it:

```
>>> lt(a,b)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.336649845037007>
>>> lf(a, b_sigmoid)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float64, numpy=2.3366498369361732>
```

Comment: thank you for your perfect response. I just wanna know whether this affects the training process other than the desired stability. I mean the optimisation is affected if we set that argument to True or False?!

Comment: The recommended usage is to set `from_logits` to True, and to skip the final sigmoid activation function. However, when doing inference, you might want to add it back to get probabilities out of the network instead of logits. Optimization should be the same if the value of the loss function is the same.